# Summarizing unregulary daily data into weekly data

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm currently analysing the impact of insider trades on stock prices, therefore I just want to create in a first step a basic overview of the ratio of buys and sales of insiders of an specific company.

Therefore, after having the overview of the ratio in general of all datpoints I want to analyse every week, but I have no Idea how to turn unregulary daily data into weekly data and then week for week analyse it.

The code snippet:

```
    mmm_transactions = df.get_insider_sales('MMM')
    mmm_transactions.rename(columns={'Transaction Type ':'Transaction'}, inplace=True)
    transactions_total = mmm_transactions.shape[0]
    mmm_transactions['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(mmm_transactions['Date'])
    mmm_transactions.index = mmm_transactions['Transaction']
    mmm_transactions = mmm_transactions['2020']
    buys = mmm_transactions.Transaction.str.count("Buy").sum()
    Sales = mmm_transactions.Transaction.str.count("Sale").sum()
    Data = {'Stats': [buys,Sales]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(Data,columns=['Stats'],index = ['Buy','Sale'])

    df.plot.pie(y='Stats',figsize=(5, 5),autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=90)
```

Because if I could weeklize the data I also my other values like shares sold (bought) could be summed up and this would make analysis much easier

Comment: Hi Hacker5preme, welcome to StackOverflow! We can help you better if you provide a concrete question you have and minimal reproducible code to go with it.